# Windows Equivalent for package.json script commands

Tags: npm, node-modules, package.json, parcel

I am using parcel and want to clean the .cache folder and also to run React frontend on 3000 while also running backend on 1234. these are my start scripts.

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "start": "npm run build-client && node index.js",
    "dev": "npm run dev-client & nodemon index.js",
    "dev-peer": "cross-env GENERATE_PEER_PORT='true' nodemon index.js",
    "build-client": "npm run clean && parcel build client/src/index.html --out-dir client/dist",
    "dev-client": "npm run clean && parcel client/src/index.html --out-dir client/dist",
    "clean": "rmdir /s/q .cache client/dist"
  },
```

I have already put the windows commands on the 'clean' script with `rmdir /s/q` but get

```
Invalid switch - "dist".
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ajax27-blockchain@1.0.0 clean: `rmdir /s/q .cache client/dist`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ajax27-blockchain@1.0.0 clean script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\shaun\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-09T11_49_08_194Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ajax27-blockchain@1.0.0 dev-client: `npm run clean && parcel client/src/index.html --out-dir client/dist`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ajax27-blockchain@1.0.0 dev-client script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\shaun\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-09T11_49_08_223Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively use rimraf npm module and it works well with windows as well.